# Antd Calendar is not displaying the proper outline

Tags: reactjs, web, calendar, frontend, antd

[image]

[image]

First and Second pictures are coding for page having and calendar.
Last picture is showing how the antd calendar is not working properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The outline is dependent on  having a css file. Antd provides one out of the box. Add this to your imports:

```
import '~antd/dist/antd.css';
```